# Validating a string's first 3 letters as uppercase with regex

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I have a question on Classic ASP regarding validating a string's first 3 letters to be uppercase while the last 4 characters should be in numerical form using regex.

For e.g.:

```
dim myString = "abc1234"
```

How do I validate that it should be `"ABC1234"` instead of `"abc1234"`?

Apologies for my broken English and for being a newbie in Classic ASP.

Comment: How many characters should be in the string, >= 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ndn has a good regex pattern for you. To apply it in Classic ASP, you just need to create a `RegExp` object that uses the pattern and then call the `Test()` function to test your string against the pattern.

For example:

```vb
Dim re
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^[A-Z]{3}.*[0-9]{4}$"  ' @ndn's pattern

If re.Test(myString) Then
    ' Match. First three characters are uppercase letters and last four are digits.
Else
    ' No match.
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Z]{3}.*[0-9]{4}$
```

Explanation:

1. Surround everything with `^$` (start and end of string) to ensure you are matching everything
2. `[A-Z]` - gives you all capital letters in the English alphabet
3. `{3}` - three of those
4. `.*` - optionally, there can be something in between (if there can't be, you can just remove this)
5. `[0-9]` - any digit
6. `{4}` - 4 of those